# Command+Tab doesn't switch between full-screen apps

Tags: macos, fullscreen

If I put iCal.app or Mail.app or iPhoto.app in full-screen mode, I'm unable to access those apps via Command+Tab from my main desktop interface. This seems like an oversight.

What's also puzzling is that if I manually switch to one of the full-screen apps (via clicking on its dock icon) and *then* use Command+Tab, I'm able to switch between that full-screen app and any other full-screen apps via Command+Tab, but as soon as I switch to a non-full-screen app, then I'm unable to return to a full-screen app via Command+Tab.

Is there a preference setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes - Go to System Preferences / Mission Control and tick "When switching to an application ..."

Comment: Perfect! I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: More like can't believe Apple missed that. It's ridiculously counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Joe - Yes.. Default behavior that is counter productive is a defect - this one counts as such.

Comment: Dan - this does not even work for me. I have that checkbox clicked in MC under system preferences. Fullscreen windows do not get included in the cycle of all-windows cycling (command-tab_ or application cycling.

Comment: Does not work on 10.11.4

Comment: [This doesn't work on Sierra.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/257369/4395)

Answer (score 0):

In Ventura I fixed this by opening System Setting, then…
go to Desktop & Dock (in the sidebar) >
Near the bottom is Mission Control. Here's the screenshot… I believe the second item is the important one to fix this.

[image]