# Command+Tab between apps does not work in Sierra

Tags: macos, spaces, bug

Since updating to macOS Sierra, many apps fail to respond correctly to Command+Tab switching.

For example, if the three most recent apps are any two other apps A and B and C, in the order A B C, Command+Tab from A briefly shows B, and then immediately switches to C.

Examples of B that exhibit this behavior include non-Apple apps (e.g. TextWrangler) as well as Apple apps (e.g. Messenger). Changing at least some apps to full screen causes them to behave correctly.

---

"Manually" switching by holding Command+Tab and selecting B fails in the same way.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you've described, so the only thing I can offer is to suggest submitting feedback and or a bug report. See http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html & https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: I can reproduce this;
1) Open Chrome and Terminal. 
2) Close both application windows and leave both apps open in the background. 
3) Open Chrome
4) Put Chrome in Full Screen Mode
5) Use Command+Tab to select Terminal
6) You'll be returned to the first desktop space and Finder will be in focus, requiring you to use Command+Tab again to use the Terminal. 

I fully agree this is a bug.

Comment: See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256063/problem-with-cmd-tab-now-that-ive-loaded-macos-sierra).

Comment: ^ force stopping the dock from the Activity Monitor seems to fix the problem.